# What's the difference between a little complex MySQL standard query and how it should be using PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement

i got this query using just mysqls default queries,

```
if(!is_empty($_GET['cidade'])){
     $cidade = safe_string_escape($_GET['cidade']);
      $cidadestr="AND cidade LIKE '%$cidade'";
}
else $cidadestr="";

if(!is_empty($_GET['dormitorios'])){
     $dormitorios = $_GET['dormitorios'];
      $dormitoriosstr="AND dormitorios = '$dormitorios'";
}
else $dormitoriosstr="";

$busca = "SELECT * FROM imoveis WHERE status = 'Publicado' $cidadestr $dormitoriosstr;
```

i change this to PDO like:

```
if(!is_empty($_GET['cidade'])){
     $cidade = safe_string_escape($_GET['cidade']);
      $cidadestr="AND cidade LIKE '%$cidade'";
}
else $cidadestr="";

if(!is_empty($_GET['dormitorios'])){
     $dormitorios = $_GET['dormitorios'];
      $dormitoriosstr="AND dormitorios = '$dormitorios'";
}
else $dormitoriosstr="";


$busca = "SELECT * FROM imoveis WHERE status = :status :cidadestr :dormitoriosstr;
$buscasql = $conn->prepare($busca);
$buscasql->bindValue(':status', 'Publicado', PDO::PARAM_STR);
$buscasql->bindValue(':cidadestr', $cidadestr, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$buscasql->bindValue(':dormitoriosstr', $dormitoriosstr, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$buscasql->execute() or die(print_r($buscasql->errorInfo()));
```

it doesn't works, i got nothing in a rowCount() or things like this, so, i guess i'm doing it wrong, so , how is a right way to do this change from simple mysql to PDO? any help?

Answer (score 0):

PDO offers a layer of abstraction which can be very useful in a portable environment. You can also query your data against different providers, such as Memcached and MySQL, although I'm not to sure whats natively supported. But it offers excellent contextual support.

Answer (score 0):

solved! did it:

```
if(!is_empty($_GET['business'])){
     $buscasql.=" AND businessLIKE :business";
}

$buscasql = $conn->prepare($busca);

if(!is_empty($_GET['business'])){
     $business= '%'.safe_string_escape($_GET['business']).'%';
     $buscasql->bindValue(':business', $business, PDO::PARAM_STR);
}
```

then bind everything... so, like we used to say 'round here '[POG](http://desciclopedia.ws/wiki/Programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o_Orientada_a_Gambiarras)'

Comment: You don't have to manually escape the parameters when using prepared statements like that, MySQL will do that for you.

Comment: And POG in English would be [WOP](http://uncyclopedia.wikia.com/wiki/Workaround-oriented_programming). `:)`